# UITableView unexpected label changing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

The cell is initially created from a xib file. Ive registered a reuse identifier in `viewDidLoad()`.
Whenever I scroll down, one specific label is redrawn partially. Cant seem to figure out whats going on with the cell, but I know that the cell is not nil. Looking for insight on why this label isn't being drawn correctly.

---

[image] 

before dragging

[image]

after dragging


**More Info:**
I can't tell, but it seems as if new cells are being drawn directly on top of the old cells. I figured this out due to the custom line divider: (`let lineView = self.createLineDivider(cell: cell)`) I added to context view of the cell. To stop the line from drawing over itself, I change the tag of every new cell.

```
  override func viewDidLoad()
   {

   super.viewDidLoad()

   let nib = UINib(nibName: "customContactDetailTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
       self.contactDetailsTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customDetailCell")
   }

func configureCell(cell: customContactDetailTableViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath) -> customContactDetailTableViewCell
{
 let sectionName = self.props[indexPath.section].keys.first!
    let contactPropLabel = self.props[indexPath.section][sectionName]![indexPath.row].keys.first!
    let contactProp = self.props[indexPath.section][sectionName]![indexPath.row][contactPropLabel]


    cell.contactDetailInfo?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.contactDetailInfo?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.contactDetailInfoTitle?.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.contactDetailInfoTitle?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    cell.contactDetailInfo?.numberOfLines = 0
    cell.contactDetailInfoTitle?.text = contactPropLabel
    cell.contactDetailInfo?.text = contactProp
    cell.contactDetailInfo?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping


    self.rowHeight = cell.bounds.height



    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customDetailCell") as? customContactDetailTableViewCell

        if cell?.tag != 212
        {
            cell?.tag = 212
            cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            let lineView = self.createLineDivider(cell: cell)
            cell?.contentView.addSubview(lineView)
        }

        return self.configureCell(cell: cell!, indexPath: indexPath)
    }
```

**Update**
Figured it out. Looks like the sporadic behavior came from the table view not updating the row height quick enough. Used this instead:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath      indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: You have word wrapping specified as the line break mode, but the cell can't expand to have more than one line, so the wrapped portion is discarded.

Comment: @Paulw11 Why can't it? that's exactly what the cell above it is doing; expanding. Although it appears to be clipping the zip code portion as well.

Comment: I don't know - the expanded cell only has one text field shown, so it is obviously configured differently.  You need to look at your cell and see why its height is constrained.

Comment: what is the name of that label here ?

Comment: @KKRocks `cell.contactDetailInfo?.text` its not clipping anymore. but the height of the row is not accurate, so the line divider is getting drawn over one of the labels